# What is the meaning of the expression 'nice to wheat you'?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, idioms, idiomatic-language, word-in-context

According to OxfordDictionaries.com, the word '[wheat](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wheat)' can be only a noun. However, in [a scene from the television cartoon *Rick and Morty*](https://youtu.be/tZHeIxBcZRs?t=14), it was used as a verb in the phrase *"nice to wheat you"*.

1. What is the meaning of the expression '**nice to wheat you**'? *(my guess is 'to ground you to the powder')*
2. Is it an idiom?

Comment: Perhaps it was "nice to eat you" - (said the spider to the fly).

Comment: @WS2 May be, according to the cartoon he has a slight lisp

Comment: Definitely a pun f*** you very much which is very close to _thank you very much_ for getting me into much trouble.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's a pun, not correct English.

The proper idiom is "Nice to meet you" but the character is throwing wheat crackers, so he substitutes the rhyming word (meet/wheat) to make a joke.

Comment: Either wheat crackers, or wheat cereal. (I'm not sure which it is, but either one explains the corny pun.)

Comment: @J.R. If you want to get technical, they're Wheat Thins :)

Comment: I'll take your word for it. (It just looked like cereal to me, the way they were stacked up in that bowl.)

Comment: They mention the brand in the cartoon: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jRB6GkFPt18

Comment: @relaxing Thanks. It looks like [malapropism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism) then

Comment: @Max is it still a malapropism if it's intentional?

Comment: @relaxing As far as I can conclude from the article above - yes, it is. Or did you mean definition malapropism in other languages?

Comment: @J.R. Would it be cornier if they were throwing popcorn?

Comment: I would not call an intentional pun on the part of the speaker a malapropism. In the case of fiction, the intent that matters is the character's, not the writer(s); Sheridan presumably intentionally created all of Mrs Malaprop's substitutions, even if *she* was unaware of the errors in the context of the play. In this case, both the screenwriters and the character intend the pun, so it is not a malapropism.

Comment: @Max No, this is a pun, and not a malapropism.

Comment: @StephenS Can you tell me shortly, what the difference between 'malapropism' and 'pun' or it is too broad question?

Comment: @Max Puns are funny because they are intentional and play on word meanings or context. Malapropisms are funny because they are nonsensical. In this case, it is a pun, because it is related to the context, not completely out of the blue.

Comment: @Max To add a little bit to Stephen S's explanation, a person who makes a pun knows what both words/phrases mean, and is trying to be funny: if we laugh at a pun, we're laughing *with* the person who made it. A person who makes a malapropism either doesn't know the right definition of both words or has misspoken/typoed the wrong term accidentally: if we laugh at a malapropism, we're laughing *at* the person who made it. (I say "if we laugh" because in real life we're more likely to groan at a pun and politely ignore a malapropism.)